# How to Use Feature Class to Feature Class After Multiple Fields Added in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I have created a model that towards the end of the model adds two new fields. I want to use Feature Class to Feature Class after the fields have been added and calculated, this way I can take advantage of the Field Mappings parameter. I am using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

This is what I have ... any thoughts on how to add Feature Class to Feature Class after the last two field calculations?

[image]

Comment: @Hornbydd When you get a chance can you perhaps convert your comment to an answer because it looks like it will be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both your add fields are adding fields to JoinedPermits you don't have to split it in the manner that you have. Simply link the output *Formation Field Calculated* as the input into *Add Well Status Field*. You can then connect your Featureclass to Featureclass to the *Well status field calculated*.